# sage pay testing error

Tags: php, opayo

im trying to test my sage pay integration but to no avail.

Here is my code:

```
private function init_sagepay(){
    extract( static::$post );
    $settings = global_data::get_settings();
    $strConnectTo = "TEST";
    $strVirtualDir = "VSPForm-Kit";
    $strYourSiteFQDN = global_data::get_web_root();  
    $strVSPVendorName = $settings->sagepay_vendor;
    $strEncryptionPassword = "z5phUfjdEB5ZX2ZY";
    $strCurrency = static::$currency;
    $strVendorEMail = $settings->sagepay_email;
    $strTransactionType = "PAYMENT";

    $strProtocol = "2.23";
    if ( $strConnectTo == "LIVE" ) 
        $strPurchaseURL = "https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp"; 
    elseif ( $strConnectTo == "TEST" )
        $strPurchaseURL = "https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspform-register.vsp";
    elseif( $strConnectTo == 'TTEST' )
        $strPurchaseURL = 'https://test.sagepay.com/Simulator/VSPServerGateway.asp?Service=VendorRegisterTx';
    else
        $strPurchaseURL = "https://test.sagepay.com/Simulator/VSPDirectGateway.asp";

    $details = self::get_member_details();
    $thisOrderDeteails = 'order details...';
    $ThisVendorTxCode = 'fdsdgfd';
    $ThisAmount = $total;
    $ThisCurrency = static::$currency;
    $ThisDescription = "description...";
    $ThisCustomerEmail = $details->email;
    $ThisCustomerName = $details->first_name . " " . $details->last_name;
    $ThisVendorEmail = $strVendorEMail;
    $ThisApplyAVSCV2 = 1;
    $ThisApply3DSecure = 1;
    $ThisDeliveryAddress = $address_line_1 . ", " . $address_line_2 . ", " . $address_line_3 . ", " . $address_line_4 . ", " . $country;
    $ThisDeliveryPostCode = $postcode;
    $address_full = $ThisDeliveryAddress . ' ' . $ThisDeliveryPostCode;

    $ThisBillingAddress = $details->address_line_1 . ", " . $details->address_line_2 . ", " . $details->address_line_3 . ", " . $details->address_line_4 . ", " . $details->country;
    $ThisBillingPostCode = $details->postcode;

    $ThisContactNumber = $details->home_number;
    $ThisContactFax = $details->fax_number;
    $ThisAllowGiftAid = '';

    $ThisShoppingBasket = 'Basket=' . count( $items ) . ':';
    foreach( $items as $item ) {
        preg_match( "#^\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]]+)\]$#is", $item, $match );
        $ThisShoppingBasket .= $match[2] . ':' . $match[1] . ':' . static::$cp . ( $match[3] / $match[1] ) . static::$cp . ':0.00:' . static::$cp . $match[3] . ':'; 
    }
    $ThisShoppingBasket .= 'Delivery:1:£4.99';

    $stuff = "VendorTxCode=" . $ThisVendorTxCode . "&";
    $stuff .= "Amount=" . $ThisAmount . "&";
    $stuff .= "Currency=" . $ThisCurrency . "&";
    $stuff .= "Description=" . $ThisDescription . "&";
    $stuff .= "SuccessURL=" . $strYourSiteFQDN . "&";
    $stuff .= "FailureURL=" . $strYourSiteFQDN . "&";

    $varArray = array('CustomerEmail','VendorEmail','CustomerName','DeliveryAddress','DeliveryPostCode','BillingAddress','BillingPostCode','ContactNumber','ContactFax','AllowGiftAid','ApplyAVSCV2','Apply3DSecure');
    foreach( $varArray as $var ) {
        if( ${'This' . $var} ) {
            $stuff .= $var . '=' . ${'This' . $var} . '&';
        }
    }
    if($ThisShoppingBasket) {
        $stuff .= $ThisShoppingBasket;
    }
    $stuff .= "EMailMessage=For an update on the status of your order please email us at $ThisVendorEmail";
    echo $stuff;
    $crypt = self::base64Encode( self::SimpleXor( $stuff,$strEncryptionPassword ) );    
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $strPurchaseURL; ?>" method="post" id="sageForm" name="form1">
        <input TYPE="hidden" name="VPSProtocol" value="<?php echo $strProtocol; ?>">
        <input TYPE="hidden" name="TxType" value="<?php echo $strTransactionType; ?>">
        <input TYPE="hidden" name="Vendor" value="<?php echo $strVSPVendorName; ?>">
        <input TYPE="hidden" name="Crypt" value="<?php echo $crypt; ?>">    
        <input name="sbbutton" type="submit" value="Checkout" class="wpcf7-submit">                  
    </form>     
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

when using "TEST" im getting an error:

```
Status Detail:  5005 : The Vendor configuration is missing or invalid
```

when using "TTEST" im getting an error:

```
VPSProtocol=2.23
Status=INVALID
StatusDetail=The VendorTxCode you supplied is an invalid length.  VendorTxCodes should be between 1 to 40 characters long
```

I cannot seem to figure this out at all. If anyone has any ideas it would be greatfuly appreciated.

EDIT: $stuff echos out:

```
VendorTxCode=fdsdgfd&Amount=45.60&Currency=GBP&Description=description...&SuccessURL=http://localhost/ecom_framework/&FailureURL=http://localhost/ecom_framework/&CustomerEmail=luke@actwebdesigns.co.uk&VendorEmail=luke@actwebdesigns.co.uk&CustomerName=Luke Snowden&DeliveryAddress=mansfield, nottinghamshire, mansfield, nottinghamshire, United Kingdom&DeliveryPostCode=ng19 8pw&BillingAddress=mansfield, nottinghamshire, mansfield, nottinghamshire, United Kingdom&BillingPostCode=ng19 8pw&ContactNumber=0165656567&ApplyAVSCV2=1&Apply3DSecure=1&Basket=3:Blue Hat - black :2:£2£:0.00:£4.00:Blue Hat - brown :3:£3£:0.00:£9.00:Blue Hat - grey :4:£4£:0.00:£16.00:Delivery:1:£4.99EMailMessage=For an update on the status of your order please email us at luke@fgfdgf.co.uk
```

Comment: Arrays, why aren't you using them? This code could be less than half this length.

Comment: I'll work on that after i figure out why the above isn't working.

Comment: It might be an idea to remove sensitive data such as your phone number and encryption password...

Comment: ...and you're definitely sure the vendor name is being supplied correctly I presume...

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to make a transaction through Direct or Form-integration method?
Looks like you have made a mix-up with the Purchse Urls...
update your purchase Urls from :

http://www.sagepay.com/developers/

and make sure they are what they should be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you are posting to a valid Sage Pay account and ensure that the vendorname is correct to stop the 5005 error.

The VendorTxCode field is limited to 40 characters.  If you are not building your string correctly you may be posting everything after the VendorTxCode ampersand into your field in error.